# Access by browser works ok ,while PHPUnit fails

Tags: php, phpunit

I am using symfony2.8 ,FOSUserBundle and PHPUnit 5.7

I can access /login by browser.

However PHPUnit fail.

So I just dump the $client->getResponse() of PHPUnit

```
$client = static::createClient();

$crawlerLogin = $client->request('GET', '/login');
print $client->getResponse()->getContent();
```

These are the header of error code.
Do you think why this happen ???

```
Failed asserting that '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <title>    Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by &quot;phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Printer.php&quot; at line 110. (500 Internal Server Error)
</title>
```

This is my phpunit.xml

/app/phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
    colors                      = "true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "false"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    syntaxCheck                 = "false"
    bootstrap                   = "bootstrap.php.cache" >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!--
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    </php>
    -->

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

</phpunit>
```

Comment: can you post the `phpunit.xml` files?

Comment: I posted my phpunit.xml